# Bing Maps without Query Strings

Tags: javascript, android, query-string, bing-maps

The [Bing Maps for Android SDK](http://bingmapsandroidsdk.codeplex.com/) is currently broken for Android versions 3.x and up. While I would like to switch to Google Maps, it just isn't an option for me right now. In any case, Bing Maps doesn't work because of a bug that was introduced in API 11 and has yet to be fixed. Android's `WebView` currently has problems handling query strings and will refuse to load HTML files with query strings. Therefore, I can't load my Bing Maps file as its URL is in the format of:

```
file:///android_asset/map.html?bingMapsKey=INSERTBINGMAPSKEYHERE&lat=WHATEVER&lon=WHATEVERLSE&zoom=10&mkt=en-US
```

Is there any way to load the map without including query strings? Should I edit the HTML file or the Javascript file and how should I do so? Well, I went through the Javascript file and I've changed out the following line of script

```
var key = "MYKEY";
// _bingMapKey = Utilities.GetQuerystring('bingMapKey', '');
_bingMapKey = key;

var options = {
            credentials : _bingMapKey,
            zoom: parseInt(Utilities.GetQuerystring('zoom', '1')),
            center: new MM.Location(parseFloat(Utilities.GetQuerystring('lat', '0')),parseFloat(Utilities.GetQuerystring('lon', '0'))),
            showDashboard : false, 
            showScalebar: false, 
            showCopyright: false,
            enableSearchLogo: false, 
            enableClickableLogo: false,
            fixedMapPosition: true };
```

However, the HTML file still isn't loading Bing Maps. I can see that an issue might come up from the fact that I'm still calling `GetQuerystring` to retrieve the zoom level and lat-lon, but I'm stuck with those. I can't hardcode zoom-level and lat-lon into the Javascript file like I can with the API key. Is there any way around this?

P.S. Javascript is tagged because Bing Maps uses Javascript to load the `MapView`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13385154/bing-maps-android-sdk-crashes-on-4-0

Comment: Another option is to switch your app over to use leaflet maps. This will allow you to still using Bing Maps tiles. The leaflet control is a bit newer and works well in Android.