# Bing maps Android SDK crashes on 4.0

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, bing-maps

after downloading the SDK from codeplex I installed BingMapsAndroidSPK.apk under bin/ folder. It freezes at earth and building logo (using both emulator and USB the handheld)
and it works fine on 2.x. (emulator ),  and already updated the BingMapsAndroid.js and map.html asset files as it says [here](http://bingmapsandroidsdk.codeplex.com/workitem/1) but it didn't work. any ideas to run it on ice cream sandwich ?

Answer (score 0):

follow this link , yu'll be able to solve the issue... 
https://bingmapsandroidsdk.codeplex.com/discussions/439647
you have to change map.html file and remove the splash screen from the code ...

Comment: The link inside that link (that has the *real* answer) seems dead.